# How to solve for any given natural number n?

Tags: matrices, elementary-number-theory, systems-of-equations

I started with hard way of putting the coefficients into a matrix. But, iz did not help.

the following system of linear equations:
[system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYC7b.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

Well, by adding your equations we have $(n-1)(x_1+...+x_n)=1+...+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.
And therefore $x_1+...+x_n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2(n-1)}$.
Now, by the $i$-th equation, $x_1+...+x_n-x_i=i$ so $\frac{n(n+1)}{2(n-1)}-x_i=i$.
Finally, $x_i=\frac{n(n+1)}{2(n-1)}-i$  $ \forall i \in \{1,...,n \} $

Comment: n-1    or n-2 ?  tha last equation has n-1 columns.. ?

Comment: to be honest I don't understand your question. I didn't mention the concept of columns anywhere, and I can't see how it can be related to the "last equation". I can see for example that "columns of the system" is a reference to the columns of the matrix formed by the coefficients of the system. But what does the expression "columns of the last equation" means?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the sum of equations :
$$(n-1)(x_{1}+..+x_{n}) = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

Now you could find $$x_{i} = \frac{n(n+1)}{2(n-1)} - i$$.

Comment: is i a complex number here or something else?

Comment: what is then a solution for a any natural number n ?   X7 is $x_{i} = \frac{7(7+1)}{2(7-1)} - i$    ? how can be written a solution in a math end form ?

Comment: @Algebra2015 $i$ means position of $x_{i}$